# Getting “Cannot find module '/app/dist'” error on deploying Angular Universal to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, npm

The heroku build runs successfully.
This is my package.json
The app runs well on development but gives error on heroku platform

```
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node dist/blog/server/main.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run blog:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/blog/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run blog:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run blog:prerender"
  },
```

The heroku log i got.
How can i solve this error?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
   ^

 Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/blog/server/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! blog@0.0.0 start: `node dist/blog/server/main.js`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the blog@0.0.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-29T21_26_22_651Z-debug.log
Starting process with command 'npm start'
```

This error Has been very hectic for me, i got this same error from Firebase deployment, so i decided to try out heroku